# What's the difference between returning something right away and returning a placeholder

Tags: python, return, return-value, variable-assignment

I have come across something like:

```
def lastFirst(firstName, lastName):
    separator = ', '
    result = lastName + separator + firstName
    return result
```

and

```
def lastFirst(firstName, lastName):
    separator = ', '
    return lastName + separator + firstName
```

and

```
def lastFirst(firstName, lastName):
    separator = ', '
    result = a_function(separator)
    return result
```

I am a bit of a functional programmer, so I like the second one more and prefer nesting i.e. `return a_function(separator)`. But is there a point in the first or third one? Would I be wrong in my preference for brevity?

Comment: Use whichever you find more readable. To me, the redundant variables are a little odd.

Comment: calling functions when you could _not_ call functions (and create variables when you're using them only once) adds some overhead.

Comment: Actually, use neither of the above examples, instead use `return lastName + ',' + firstName` instead. Also, your `lastFirst` is potentially not even needed. It seems to me that this was overthought.

Comment: The argument that has been made to me is about the linter and using a debugger for breakpoints, but that does not seem right especially since `pylint` does not seem to suggest a difference between either. @scharette I just found some short examples online to ask my question; most of the code is not that trivial.